# Parse HTML with Beautiful Soup. Return text from specific tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I can parse the full argument of a html Tag addressing it over a unix shell script like this:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3

# import the module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# define your object
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"))

# get the tag
print(soup(itemprop="name"))
```

where `itemprop="name"` uniquely identifies the required tag.

the output is something like

```
[<span itemprop="name">
                    Blabla &amp; Bloblo</span>]
```

Now I would like to return only the `Bla Bla Blo Blo` part.

my attempt was to do:

```
print(soup(itemprop="name").getText())
```

but I get an error message like `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'getText'`

it worked experimentally in other contexts such as

```
print(soup.find('span').getText())
```

So what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `soup` object as a callable returns a *list* of results, as if you used `soup.find_all()`. See the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all):

> Because `find_all()` is the most popular method in the Beautiful Soup search API, you can use a shortcut for it. If you treat the `BeautifulSoup` object or a `Tag` object as though it were a function, then it’s the same as calling `find_all()` on that object.

Use [`soup.find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) to find just the *first* match:

```
soup.find(itemprop="name").get_text()
```

or index into the resultset:

```
soup(itemprop="name")[0].get_text()
```

Comment: unfortunatly it did not work on my machine. Your first suggestion results in `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'` and your second suggestion in `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @joaoal: then *no matches were found*. Are you sure the element you are looking for exists in the page source? Note that what you see in the browser *could have been loaded by JavaScript code* and is not necessarily part of the HTML you load from the URL.

Comment: as I mentioned: When I do `soup(itemprop="name")` he returns the whole line `[<span itemprop="name">Blabla &amp; Bloblo</span>]`. But he does not find anything with `soup.find`. This part of the html doc might be loaded by javascript but is there no way to parse it then? I mean formerly I parsed this line with Regex... but i would rather prefer to use something more adapted to html.

Comment: @joaoal: Yet you get an index error when you use `soup(itemprop="name")[0]`; clearly you are looking at a *series* of different documents, not just the one where `itemprop="name"` exists.

Comment: @joaoal: in other words, I suspect you are using a loop or other means of loading multiple pages and at least *one* has `<span itemprop="name">` defined, but at least *one other* does not and you are getting confused as to when that error is thrown. Since `soup(itemprop="name").getText()` *always* fails (wether the result is empty or not) you did not encounter that possibility before, but now you do.

Comment: ??? I don't know why..... but now it works...thanks for your help - I really appreciate! Just for completion. i did not use a loop so far, i processed only one single html doc. If I would do it in a loop and there was one document that did not had the line, could I use one of your suggestions above?